# Xcode memory debugging

Tags: xcode, debugging

Is there any good treatment of Xcode code and memory out there? Like any book or resources? I am mixing Objective-C and plain C within an Xcode project and the memory usage keeps on growing. I am interested in in-depth treatment of the underlying concepts as well as tools including Apple Instruments. Something like 100 pages would be very welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has several documents about memory management. For instance:

- [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)
- [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000127i)

Even if the second one is about CF, it also explains lots of concepts available in Objective-C.

There are also great videos about memory management on the WWDC sessions, especially about OS X (or iOS) memory management internals and Instruments.
You can download them from iTunes if you're a registered developer:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

Comment: I guess there is no book then. I'll stick with these.

Comment: I might add that the plain C I'm referring to is not part of CF.

Comment: The videos at developer conference really helps. Also the 2010 ones too. Great.